# Javascript: How can I replace newlines from a textarea to a div element?

Tags: javascript, textarea

This jsfiddle explains it all
https://jsfiddle.net/qphoria/jh7p0oq2/1/

How do I make the div appear as multiple lines without showing the literal `<br>` tags?

Answer (score 2):

Could probably try

```
$('#display').html(str);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j56vdyfa/1/

Comment: Ugh.. so obvious... kicking myself.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.html()` instead

`$('#display').html(str);`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jh7p0oq2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

use .html() will taking the str as html and render it. .text() will only render str as text.

```
 $('#display').html(str);
```